# Parsing Search Result with MGTwitterEngine in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, nsdictionary

I'm using Matt Gemmell's amazing MGTwitterEngine for an iPhone project, and my lack of familiarity with Obj-C and JSON parsing is making a simple job seem rather daunting.

I've read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197996/mgtwitterengine-and-iphone), and while it helps me understand how the data is structured, I still can't seem to be able to parse it.

If I do an NSLog of the output of getSearchResultsForQuery like so:

```
NSLog(@"getSearchResultsForQuery: connectionIdentifier = %@", [myTwitterEngine getSearchResultsForQuery:@"#joke" sinceID:0 startingAtPage:1 count:5]);
```

I get this in the console:

```
2009-12-05 00:14:46.518 Entendu[90565:207] getSearchResultsForQuery: connectionIdentifier = DED541CB-A3DA-4C04-8B23-ED20D13B147E
2009-12-05 00:14:46.843 Entendu[90565:207] Request succeeded for connectionIdentifier = DED541CB-A3DA-4C04-8B23-ED20D13B147E
2009-12-05 00:14:46.884 Entendu[90565:207] Got search results for DED541CB-A3DA-4C04-8B23-ED20D13B147E:
(
        {
        "created_at" = 1259989857;
        "from_user" = royanramadhan;
        "from_user_id" = 64716299;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6361369664;
        "iso_language_code" = sv;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/455943541/Dup_01_Foto006_normal.jpg";
        source = "<a href=\"http://m.twitter.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">mobile web</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "kenapa di keybord komputer tulisnya \"ENTER\" ? #joke";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259988269;
        "from_user" = alivenkickin;
        "from_user_id" = 2547330;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6360783744;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/65068323/calvin_normal.jpg";
        source = "<a href=\"http://www.tweetdeck.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "RT @andycrash: A nice, calm and respectable lady went into the pharmacy...#joke http://bit.ly/BGDfJ";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259988217;
        "from_user" = lilbytes;
        "from_user_id" = 18943691;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6360764474;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/477338701/twitterProfilePhoto_normal.jpg";
        source = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">web</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "RT @Pyeman: LOL - Great post RT @cahlan: RT @jac_: Christmas light fun: http://bit.ly/828q7K #lol #funny #joke #christmas";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259987890;
        "from_user" = jscognam;
        "from_user_id" = 41472147;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6360648482;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/432856397/AJ_normal.png";
        source = "<a href=\"http://www.tweetdeck.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetDeck</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "RT @jokestweet: Give me ambiguity or give me something else. #joke";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259987587;
        "from_user" = jokestweet;
        "from_user_id" = 54008906;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6360534281;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/403925746/jokes_twitter_normal.jpg";
        source = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">web</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "Give me ambiguity or give me something else. #joke";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259987426;
        "from_user" = RickyRicardoABN;
        "from_user_id" = 79758746;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6360472740;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/554599647/l_92120d47e5744fee9da32c4ac71b9eee_normal.jpg";
        source = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">web</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "#Why do people tell you when they are speechless? #joke";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259984750;
        "from_user" = socialEspeaking;
        "from_user_id" = 80950838;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6359413973;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/542502866/jack_sm_normal.jpg";
        source = "<a href=\"http://apiwiki.twitter.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\">API</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "RT @andycrash A nice, calm and respectable lady went into the pharmacy...#joke http://x4.lol.0sp.in o_O";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259984140;
        "from_user" = oceanbutterfly7;
        "from_user_id" = 70740820;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6359164521;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/558958306/Tiger-puppy_love_normal.jpg";
        source = "<a href=\"/devices\" rel=\"nofollow\">txt</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "@jokestweet: \" Hire a teenage while they still know everything,\" #joke";
        "to_user" = jokestweet;
        "to_user_id" = 54008906;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259983842;
        "from_user" = "Fab_DTY";
        "from_user_id" = 51115644;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6359037805;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/515204077/moto_0326_normal.jpeg";
        source = "<a href=\"http://ubertwitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">UberTwitter</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "RT @nutshellcards: Energizer Bunny arrested, charged with battery. lmao #Joke";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259983640;
        "from_user" = chunyip;
        "from_user_id" = 1221169;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6358953626;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://s.twimg.com/a/1259808911/images/default_profile_6_normal.png";
        source = "<a href=\"http://mobileways.de/gravity\" rel=\"nofollow\">Gravity</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "RT @jokestweet: If electricity comes from electrons, does that mean that morality comes from morons? #joke";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259983356;
        "from_user" = nutshellcards;
        "from_user_id" = 54486591;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6358837191;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/515618469/blue_normal.png";
        source = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">web</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "Energizer Bunny arrested, charged with battery. lmao\n#Joke";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259983222;
        "from_user" = sagewhistler;
        "from_user_id" = 3737203;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6358780332;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/552759084/cowboycig_normal.GIF";
        source = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">web</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "#Joke \"What's the shotgun for?\" asks the homeowner. The bear remover replies, \"If the bear knocks me off the roof, shoot the dog.\" [end]";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259983181;
        "from_user" = sagewhistler;
        "from_user_id" = 3737203;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6358763080;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/552759084/cowboycig_normal.GIF";
        source = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">web</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "#Joke The bear will then be subdued enough for me to put him in the cage in the back of the van.\"He hands the shotgun to the homeowner...";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259983144;
        "from_user" = sagewhistler;
        "from_user_id" = 3737203;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6358748440;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/552759084/cowboycig_normal.GIF";
        source = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">web</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "#Joke When the bear falls off, the pit bull is trained to grab his testicles and not let go...";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "created_at" = 1259983112;
        "from_user" = sagewhistler;
        "from_user_id" = 3737203;
        geo = <null>;
        id = 6358736099;
        "iso_language_code" = en;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/552759084/cowboycig_normal.GIF";
        source = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/\">web</a>";
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
        text = "#Joke \"I'm going to put this ladder up against the roof, then I'm going to go up there & knock the bear off the roof with this baseball bat";
        "to_user_id" = <null>;
    },
        {
        "completed_in" = 0;
        "max_id" = 6361369664;
        "next_page" = "?page=2&max_id=6361369664&q=%23joke";
        page = 1;
        query = "%23joke";
        "refresh_url" = "?since_id=6361369664&q=%23joke";
        "results_per_page" = 15;
        "since_id" = 0;
        "source_api_request_type" = 37;
    }
)
```

The strange thing is I have count:5, yet I'm getting many more results.

For the actual parsing, would I save the output to an NSArray, and then an NSDictionary, which I can query with valueForKey:@"text" for example?

I know two delegate methods are being called too (requestSucceeded: and searchResultsReceived:forRequest: ) but I'm not sure how this affects parsing.

The actual delegate method for searchResultsReceived:forRequest: is:

```
- (void)searchResultsReceived:(NSArray *)searchResults forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier
{
 NSLog(@"Got search results for %@:\r%@", connectionIdentifier, searchResults);
}
```

This suggests that the results are actually stored by variable searchResults.

Still, how do I get the individual strings?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The searchResults variable in your delegate is an array of dictionaries. You just index into that array and then start grabbing values for the keys in the dictionaries. For example

```
- (void)searchResultsReceived:(NSArray *)searchResults 
                   forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier
{
    if ([searchResults count] > 0)
    {
        NSDictionary *result = [searchResults objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *fromUser = [result valueForKey:@"from_user"];
        NSString *fromUserID = [result valueForKey@"from_user_id"];
        // ...
        NSString *text = [result valueForKey@"text"];

        NSLog(@"User %@(%@): %@", fromUser, fromUserID, text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This gives me a way to go on ahead and work on the data. 

To access the individual strings out of the scope of the delegate function, could I set a return type of Array and return one with just the information I need? 

Or just return the original array itself to do the extraction elsewhere?

Again, thanks!

Comment: You can just create an NSArray instance variable (ivar) property and hold onto it, e.g. [self setItems:searchResults]; This would require your instance variable be declared as a property like, @property (assign) NSArray *items; in your .h and then @synthesize items in the .m.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what parsing you need to do.  You're supposed to be supplying a delegate to the engine (like a callback, but an actual object), which the engine will use to notify you when it has results.  The results should be coming back as an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`s, which means you don't have to do any parsing at all.